# inverse matrix np.linalg.inv in Python, gives weird results, why?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, inverse

I have a matrix

```
A = array([[1.09624842, 1.11117215, 1.1286472 , 1.14919556, 1.17347793,
        1.20234278, 1.23689824, 1.27861975, 1.32951655],
       [1.11117215, 1.1286472 , 1.14919556, 1.17347793, 1.20234278,
        1.23689824, 1.27861975, 1.32951655, 1.392398  ],
       [1.1286472 , 1.14919556, 1.17347793, 1.20234278, 1.23689824,
        1.27861975, 1.32951655, 1.392398  , 1.47131753],
       [1.14919556, 1.17347793, 1.20234278, 1.23689824, 1.27861975,
        1.32951655, 1.392398  , 1.47131753, 1.57234955],
       [1.17347793, 1.20234278, 1.23689824, 1.27861975, 1.32951655,
        1.392398  , 1.47131753, 1.57234955, 1.70503235],
       [1.20234278, 1.23689824, 1.27861975, 1.32951655, 1.392398  ,
        1.47131753, 1.57234955, 1.70503235, 1.88525391],
       [1.23689824, 1.27861975, 1.32951655, 1.392398  , 1.47131753,
        1.57234955, 1.70503235, 1.88525391, 2.14160156],
       [1.27861975, 1.32951655, 1.392398  , 1.47131753, 1.57234955,
        1.70503235, 1.88525391, 2.14160156, 2.53125   ],
       [1.32951655, 1.392398  , 1.47131753, 1.57234955, 1.70503235,
        1.88525391, 2.14160156, 2.53125   , 3.1875    ]])
```

and using `np.linalg.inv` I get results

```
invA = array([[ 9.03216714e+13, -4.06448796e+14,  7.70561913e+14,
        -8.00202097e+14,  4.95034612e+14, -1.85465207e+14,
         4.07006142e+13, -4.71978384e+12,  2.17073788e+11],
       [-4.06445370e+14,  1.82901213e+15, -3.46751917e+15,
         3.60090497e+15, -2.22765654e+15,  8.34595116e+14,
        -1.83153441e+14,  2.12391394e+13, -9.76838505e+11],
       [ 7.70548134e+14, -3.46748639e+15,  6.57381842e+15,
        -6.82670621e+15,  4.22326723e+15, -1.58225687e+15,
         3.47229858e+14, -4.02661108e+13,  1.85193700e+12],
       [-8.00179401e+14,  3.60083319e+15, -6.82663466e+15,
         7.08926102e+15, -4.38570264e+15,  1.64311714e+15,
        -3.60586561e+14,  4.18150920e+13, -1.92318186e+12],
       [ 4.95014910e+14, -2.22758666e+15,  4.22317467e+15,
        -4.38565249e+15,  2.71314734e+15, -1.01649147e+15,
         2.23072376e+14, -2.58684453e+13,  1.18975766e+12],
       [-1.85455567e+14,  8.34558774e+14, -1.58220293e+15,
         1.64307835e+15, -1.01647909e+15,  3.80828905e+14,
        -8.35743684e+13,  9.69167331e+12, -4.45746509e+11],
       [ 4.06979905e+13, -1.83143178e+14,  3.47213684e+14,
        -3.60573544e+14,  2.23066874e+14, -8.35733246e+13,
         1.83405389e+13, -2.12686037e+12,  9.78203657e+10],
       [-4.71942267e+12,  2.12376932e+13, -4.02637495e+13,
         4.18130782e+13, -2.58674953e+13,  9.69143539e+12,
        -2.12683472e+12,  2.46639084e+11, -1.13436657e+10],
       [ 2.17054909e+11, -9.76761785e+11,  1.85180906e+12,
        -1.92306915e+12,  1.18970154e+12, -4.45730911e+11,
         9.78181643e+10, -1.13435473e+10,  5.21725039e+08]])
```

I use it for solving equations in python. However, the results which I get are totally wrong, I checked the matrix and (A@invA).astype(int) isn't even close to the identity matrix.

```
(A@invA).astype(int) = array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I tried to get the inverse matrix in Matlab and I got totally different results and I got an identity matrix by multiplying the A*invA using results in Matlab. Could someone explain to me what's going on and how to fix it :)? I tried to do inv matrix multiplication on random arrays and everything was working fine...

Comment: WIth values like `e15`, I suspect the determinate is close to 0.  In other words your array is practically singular, and the inverse becomes unreliable.  There is a `pinv` that gets around some of those singularity problem.

Comment: `np.linalg.det(A)` gives `-5.8999e-39`. Thanks @hpaulj, TIL `pinv`, works pretty well in this case.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks that really works well. What's the secret behind it :D

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your error. Copied A as-is, then did `B = np.linalg.inv(A)`, `(A@B)` and `(A@B).astype(int)`. Both give something very close to identity. What version of numpy are you using?

Comment: Also, my `B` looks very different from your `invA`. I wonder if the newer versions of numpy fail over to `pinv` at some point?

Comment: Hi @MadPhysicist I don't think it's a case of the version, that would be strange. My np version is '1.18.1'

Comment: @MaciekWoźniak. I agree. Mine's 1.18.5

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

**@hpaulj**

for the answer.

Since the matrix is almost **singular one** we should use `np.linalg.pinv` instead. It solves the problem!